# Why do i have to multiply the convolution value times tpas?

Tags: signal-processing, octave, convolution

What does the commented line do? More specifically, why do I have the `conv` function times `tpas` value?

```matlab
tstart=0;
tstop=0.1;
tpas=0.0001;
f=100;

t=tstart:tpas:tstop;
x=0+10*t;
subplot(3,1,1);
plot(t,x,'linewidth',2);
axis([0 0.1001 0 1]);
grid;

h=1*exp(-f*t);
subplot(3,1,2);
plot(t,h,'linewidth',2);
axis([0 0.1001 0 1]);
grid;

t2=2*tstart:tpas:2*tstop;

y=conv(x,h) * tpas; % what does this line do?

subplot(3,1,3);
plot(t2,y,'r','linewidth',2);
axis();
grid;
```

I posted the whole code for context but really I just need to know what happens when I multiply the convolution value with `tpas`.

Answer (score 0):

Your filter is `h=1*exp(-f*t)`, which is sampled at time values `t=tstart:tpas:tstop`

The number of simples in your filter is `(tstop-tstart)/tpas`.  The integral (just the sum of those samples) is therefore proportional to `1/tpas`.

The convolution will multiply your signal by this factor, so the result is multiplied by `tpas` to correct it.

Comment: "The integral (just the sum of those samples)" -- I guess it is exactly the difference between the integral and the sum that is being accounted for.